# Why does my crypto API return the wrong string?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the code to return one title from the API. For example:

I want this title on my p tag: Ripple Lawsuit: Here Is the Key Point of SEC’s Argument per James K. Filan

HTML what l want but not getting:

```
<div class="box" id="insert-news">
        <div class="title">Marketplace </div>
        <h2>Live News</h2>
        <p><span class='highlight'>News Article</span></p>
        <p>`Ripple Lawsuit: Here Is the Key Point of SEC’s Argument per James K. Filan`</p>
    </div>
```

My actual code

```
<div class="box" id="insert-news">
        <div class="title">Marketplace </div>
        <h2>Live News</h2>
        <p><span class='highlight'>News Article</span></p>
        <p>(it's a different title from the API)</p>
    </div>
```

```
function getData(){
    fetch('https://api.coinstats.app/public/v1/news?skip=0&limit=10').then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
        console.log(data.news[2].title);
        let newsTitle ='';
        data.news.map((values)=>{
            newsTitle = `<div class="title">Marketplace </div>
        <h2>Live News</h2>
        <p><span class='highlight'>News Article</span></p>
        <p>${values.title}</p>
    </div>`;
        })
        document.getElementById('insert-news').innerHTML = newsTitle;
    })
}

getData();
```

Comment: Everything is possible, but the question is not clear. You get a list of news, and then what do you want to do? how can I filter them for output?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I think what l meant to say is the output for my code is not what l am expecting. I am wanting 1 title from the API to display on my HTML but it showcases a different title to which l had not indexed or wanted. I want index [0].

Comment: @SwaD I have tried to include '${values.title[0]} to grab the fist title but it keeps showing up with a different title.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to reach is to display all news inside `insert-news` container

```
function getData() {
  fetch("https://api.coinstats.app/public/v1/news?skip=0&limit=10")
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      document.getElementById("insert-news").innerHTML = data.news
        .map(
          (values) =>
            `<div class="title">Marketplace </div>
      <h2>Live News</h2>
      <p><span class='highlight'>News Article</span></p>
      <p>${values.title}</p>
  </div>`
        )
        .join("");
    });
}
```

Comment: I know it's not many lines of code, but remember to write a paragraph or two of what were your changes and the base for your suggestion. *"something like this"* is not an answer.

Comment: What if l want just 1 news title? When l add index it just gives me one letter of the title l want.